# Is the Fourier transform a special case of this version of the Yoneda lemma?

Tags: category-theory, fourier-analysis, topological-groups

The (co)Yoneda lemma tells us that for a presheaf $F\in \hat{\mathbb{C}}$, the following formula holds: $$ F=\int^{c\in\mathbb{C}} Fc\ \times\ h_{c}\ , $$ where $h_c$ is a representable presheaf for $c$. Is there some well-known way to derive the formula for the Fourier transform of an $L^1 (G)$ function on $G^{\wedge}$ $$ \hat{f}(\chi)=\int_{G} f(x)\overline{\chi(x)}d\mu(x)\ , $$ where $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $G$, as a special case of the first formula? I'm not very knowledgeable at all on this abstract rendition of the Fourier transform, but I have been curious lately on the relationship between the Yoneda embedding and Fourier analysis. I am approaching this problem with a background in category theory, not analysis.

I really don't have motivating evidence that there is some connection between these two concepts, and I am quite aware that this may be a ridiculous hunch. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I believe this is nothing more than a (deliberate) coincidence of notation.

Comment: What is the notation supposed to be reminding us of? Deliberate for what reason?

Comment: Well, for instance, the apparent analogy you bring up.

Comment: Alright, gotcha. I wasn't sure if there were other important ideas to draw here. Thanks.

Comment: The analogy you noticed can be pushed very, very far: read this article http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/25/5/25-05.pdf notice in particular how you can define "convolutions" and "fourier transforms" via "multiplicative kernels", and a convolution product in such a way that fourier transforms are isometries (!) commuting with convolutions (!!).

Comment: @tetrapharmakon Oh, thank you!